# Legal meld in canasta

Tags: canasta

If a queen is on the discard pile and I have 3 queens in my hand and 2 aces and a wild card 2 can I pick up the pile and make my first meld. I need 90 to meld.

Comment: Even if you only had 2 Queens in your hand, you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

Quick counting gives you 90 points without the pile. Even with a queen less in the hand you would be able to pick up the pile.

- 3xQ = 30
- 2xA = 40
- 2   = 20